# How to run javascript function using phantomJS php or MTS

Tags: php, phantomjs

index.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showtext()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {name: $('input').val()},
        success: function(d){
            $('#show').text(d);
        }
    })
}
</script>
<input type="text" value="John">
<button id="clickme" onclick="showtext()">click me</button>
<div id="show"></div>
```

as we can see, there is 2 way to get string from div#show: click button or run showtext().

i spend 3 hours for learning [phantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/) and [MTS](https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS), but im stuck at this moment. MTS always throw error `showtext() is not a valid function name`, while phantomJS is not running at all (stuck). i try everything i found in SO and google. but still get nothing.

this is my phantomjs code

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}

page.open('http://creativecoder.xyz/test/', function(status) {

    page.evaluate(function() {
        showtext();
        var a = document.getElementById("show").innerHTML;
        console.log('xx: '+ a);
    });

    phantom.exit();

});



root@ga-ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:/var/www/html/test# phantomjs test.js
^C
root@ga-ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:/var/www/html/test# phantomjs test.js
^C
root@ga-ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:/var/www/html/test# phantomjs test.js
^C
root@ga-ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:/var/www/html/test# phantomjs test.js
```

i always force close the process because never stop and return nothing.

this is another script using jquery

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://creativecoder.xyz/test/', function() {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            var a = 'asdsad';
            $("#clickme").click();
            a = $('#show').html();
            console.log(a); //overide a
        });
        phantom.exit()
    });
});
```

and still got nothing.

how to run showtext() /doing click then get text from div#show using both library?

Comment: Can you provide some php code to see what cause the error

Comment: updated . thanks for ur attention

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `page.evaluate` you have to check the status argument, and don't use `page.onConsoleMessage` it was made for debugging purpose, instead you have to tell evaluate function to return whatever you want from the page and then use it. look at my example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

// I'm trying here to simulate a normal browser, you can remove this part of code if you want
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/538.1';
page.viewportSize = { width: 1600, height: 794 };

// open page
page.open('http://creativecoder.xyz/test/', function (status) {

    // checking status
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('cannot open page');
        phantom.exit();
    }

    var result  = page.evaluate(function() {

        // click button 
        document.getElementById('clickme').click();

        // get text result
        var res = document.getElementById('show').innerText;

        return res;

    });

    console.log(result);

    phantom.exit();

});
```

You can also use `page.render('img.png')` it will give a screenshot of the current page, it's like a debugger to see what exactly happens.

Comment: if i use http://creativecoder.xyz (my own domain) or google.com , my shell will not stop running and not return anything. but if i change into bing.com , the script is running properly

Comment: ohy, actually i;m using status, but to make it simple, i was cutting it.

Comment: Which version of PhantomJs are you using ?

Comment: my version is 1.9.0

Comment: it's an old version with a lot of problems, I'm using 2.1.1, I suggest you to read [troubleshooting](http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html) page and try to implements onError event maybe it shows you the problem, if the problem persist, you can do an upgrade from [here](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs)

Comment: i run 1.9.0 in my VPS. now i still try run 2.1.1 in my windows desktop. i'll report my result later

Comment: yep. my windows doing fine. btw, i got NULL / EMPTY result from your script. i try edit your code, but still get empty result

Comment: the problem is not there I think, there was an issue in 1.9.0 version it can't logs to stdout, try to use `system.stdout.writeLine( 'console: ' + msg );` but before that you should import the system module: `var system = require('system');`

Comment: im using 2.1.1 in my windows. i not using 1.9 at this moment